# Downloaded upgrade to windows 10 will not install

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I have downloaded Windows 10 upgrade (on Windows 8.1 Home x64) and I want to install, but nothing happens.

First I have closed the Terms & conditions window and it said `Deleting files`.

Then I have accepted Terms & conditions and have setup some schedule before just to postspone the installation, but now after clicking on `OK, continue` appears `We are working on it` and then the window closes and nothing happens.

[image]

Is there a way how to reset or repeat or fix the upgrade process?

---

This is what I see in Windows Update, though I did not cancel it explicitly, it seems it got cancelled, how to un-cancel it?

[image]

WU error code is 8024000B.

---

I will add here for completeness what I did and what happened:

1. Confirmed download of Windows 10
2. When Terms & Conditions window first appeared I have closed it with windows X close button
3. Windows said: deleting files
4. Then I was still able to open and accept Terms & Conditions without any download
5. I have created some schedule to not to be bothered by the installation
6. When I wanted to upgrade later nothing happened
7. I did `wuauclt /updatenow`
8. Windows update downloaded 546 kB of some data named `Windows 10 Upgrade`
9. Everything was OK - upgrade successful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Windows Media Creation Tool which you can [**download here**.](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)

This helps you to upgrade to windows 10 or lets you create a USB install drive.

---

By providing the additional information I was able to find a possible solution provided by microsoft. You can find it [**here**.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/windows-update-error-8024000b#1TC=windows-7)

It seems that Windows Update can't read a file (Update Manifest), to solve this you can follow the instructions:

1. Click **Windows+R**
2. Paste "`Cmd /c ren %systemroot%\System32\Spupdsvc.exe Spupdsvc.old`" without the quotes.
3. Click **Ok** and run the **Updates** again.

---

Another method could be to run cmd.exe and enter "wuauclt.exe /updatenow". That starts the upgrade process again.

Comment: This is interesting and helpful, I would like also know the way how to fix this within Windows Update.

Comment: `Cmd /c ren %systemroot%\System32\Spupdsvc.exe Spupdsvc.old` - have tried before, it does not work. `wuauclt.exe /updatenow` seems to be working - download started anew. I have just closed the window and the downloaded upgrade was deleted - it even wrote `deleting files` - probably some bug.